# NSTableView animation inconsistant

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview, appkit

I have a NSTableView which intermittently will stop animating and updating itself correctly, leading to a terrible user experience.

```
let oldRows = filteredDocuments
let newRows = newFilteredDocuments
let diff = oldRows.diff(newRows)
filteredDocuments = newFilteredDocuments

if (diff.results.count > 0) {
    let deletionIndexPaths = NSMutableIndexSet()
    diff.deletions.forEach { deletionIndexPaths.addIndex($0.idx) }
    let insertionIndexPaths = NSMutableIndexSet()
    diff.insertions.forEach { insertionIndexPaths.addIndex($0.idx) }

    self.tableView?.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView?.removeRowsAtIndexes(deletionIndexPaths, withAnimation: NSTableViewAnimationOptions.EffectFade)
    self.tableView?.insertRowsAtIndexes(insertionIndexPaths, withAnimation: NSTableViewAnimationOptions.SlideLeft)
    self.tableView?.endUpdates()
}
```

There seems to be no logic to when it stops animating, and in the many tests I've done it feels almost like it's build related.  Interestingly it never stops animating when I am profiling...

It's as if something on the main thread is clogging up the UI and then the NSTableView times out and cancels the update - but I have no idea how I can debug this.

Comment: I guess all you can do is make sure all the above code is running on the main thread (wrap it in `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {...}`) and try dispatching work that might block to a background thread and see if it improves. Maybe some cleverly placed log statements will help you ensure that this code is being called at the proper times. Table views are difficult to debug.

Comment: This question doesn't contain enough info to reproduce the problem. See [mcve]

Comment: Can you please attached a sample project which reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 1):

How about if you do one and then the other? I just recently did something similar when I needed to insert a cell AND scroll, which lead to a poor user experience. The solution was to add a slight delay. Not sure if this is what you're trying to accomplish base on the small code snippet, but here we go:

```
let oldRows = filteredDocuments
let newRows = newFilteredDocuments
let diff = oldRows.diff(newRows)
filteredDocuments = newFilteredDocuments

if (diff.results.count > 0) {
    let deletionIndexPaths = NSMutableIndexSet()
    diff.deletions.forEach { deletionIndexPaths.addIndex($0.idx) }
    let insertionIndexPaths = NSMutableIndexSet()
    diff.insertions.forEach { insertionIndexPaths.addIndex($0.idx) }

    self.tableView?.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView?.removeRowsAtIndexes(deletionIndexPaths, withAnimation: NSTableViewAnimationOptions.EffectFade)
    self.tableView?.endUpdates()

    let delay = 0.35
    let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) // Hate this syntax
    dispatch_after(delay, dispatch_get_main_queue(), { [weak self] in
        self?.tableView?.beginUpdates()
        self?.tableView?.insertRowsAtIndexes(insertionIndexPaths, withAnimation: NSTableViewAnimationOptions.SlideLeft)
        self?.tableView?.endUpdates()
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks Doug for you thought - I tried it out but makes no difference... it's really strange.

Comment: Have you tried playing around with different delay times? I'm unfamiliar with the begin and end updates syntax, but it seems like it's for some batch processing. Have you tried experimenting with not using it?

Comment: Not sure why this compiled, but I just noticed that you are using NSMutableIndexSet, when I think you meant to use [NSIndexPath]... or maybe Set<NSIndexPath> (an array of NSIndexPath or a Set of NSIndexPath, respectively). If this works, let me know and I'll submit it as an answer.